# How to use variable from a while (foreach) statement in a query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this first query

```
 <?php 
       while($empsheetpanel=mysqli_fetch_array($resultempsheets)){

 ?>
```

Under that I have placed this second query in order to get data from the first query

```
 <?php
 $sql="SELECT * From my_table WHERE id="$empsheetpanel['employee_id']" ";
 $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
 ?>
<?php } ;?>
```

I know this is improper and incorrect. What's the correct syntax to retrieve the `$empsheetpanel['employee_id']` from the first query?

Comment: Don't do that. Write a single query that joins the two tables.

Comment: @Barmar : Okay... but I think it wouldn't accomplish what I'm trying to do here... I really need the dynamic id... Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Why wouldn't the ID be dynamic in a join?

Comment: @Barmar: I know what Join is. I actually need to tell the program to look for a specific id. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Barmar : like if I would write WHERE id="12345" the program needs to know that. A JOIN wont tell it.

Comment: But you're not getting a specific ID, you're getting every ID returned by the first query in a loop. That's what a join does.

Comment: @Barmar: You're not understanding me. The solution you gave is actually what I need not a JOIN. I know how to combine multiple tables to get desired data. Thats not what I need here. I'll mark you as solution anyway

Comment: @Barmar: Even if I join I would still need to tell the program WHERE id="specific id 12345" etc.

Comment: @Barmar : Its a huge rethoric

Comment: That goes in the `WHERE some conditions here` part of the joined query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.` to concatenate strings:

```
$sql="SELECT * From my_table WHERE id=" . $empsheetpanel['employee_id'];
```

or you can use string interpolation:

```
$sql="SELECT * From my_table WHERE id={$empsheetpanel['employee_id']}";
```

But a better solution is not to do this as separate queries in a loop. Join this table with your original query.

So if your first query was:

```
SELECT * FROM my_other_table WHERE some conditions here
```

you would join them together as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_other_table
JOIN my_table ON my_table.id = my_other_table.employee_id
WHERE some conditions here
```

Each row of this result will contain the combination of data from the two tables. If `my_table` might not have matching rows, you should use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you. This will do {$empsheetpanel['employee_id']}

Answer (score 0):

use join like this

```
"SELECT t1.*,t2.column name FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.employee_id "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In your first query you can get your result like this:
Your Query:
<?php 
while($empsheetpanel=mysqli_fetch_array($resultempsheets)){
?>

<?php
$sql="SELECT * From my_table WHERE id="$empsheetpanel['employee_id']" ";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
?>
<?php } ;?>

Response:
<?php 
   $sql = "SELECT * From `my_table`";
   $resultempsheets = mysql_query($sql);
   while($empsheetpanel = mysqli_fetch_array($resultempsheets))
   {
      // put the array index beacuse you are using "mysqli_fetch_array". I am using index "0" here.
      echo $empsheetpanel[0];
      // if you are using "mysqli_fetch_assoc". you can use the filed name to get the value.
      $empsheetpanel['employee_id'];
   }
```

?>

```
   In your second query you are using the wrong ";" semicolon to terminate the script. you put after the variable define.
```